# Has someone used heat shrinking PTFE for a gas tight connection(1/4" OD)?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, connections

The question is in the title.
More details: pressure up 7 psi max, temp up to 400F.

Fluid is mixed gases. Chemical compatibility is not an issue.
Connection will be around a smaller stainless steel tube inserted in the ptfe heat shrinking element.

The insertion depth can be long  up to 1" if needed.

If this possible, we assume it wont be an accepted industrial practice, but our application is in a lab environment where we can safely try it.

The space is so cramped we don't have room for off the shelf connectors ( at least the ones we know about) and we would very much like to avoid the cost of redesigning it for this.

So my question is really to know if someone has tried it and whether or not it was successful.
Thanks

Comment: It looks like it can be done and St Gobain provides some tubing just for that, see https://www.processsystems.saint-gobain.com/products/ptfe-heat-shrink-tubing

Comment: I would doubt this works on H2 which can penetrate PTFE.  That's what we use for SLA's in sealed battery boxes to vent slow outgassing but block water unless it has some additive.

Comment: thanks for that. No H2 in our gas stream so we are good on that front. I guess we are going to test it and sees how it goes